# Who was Jethro? What religion did he and his daughter Zipporah practice prior to her becoming the wife of Moses?

Tags: biblical-basis

In the Hebrew Bible, Jethro is the name given as Moses' father-in-law, a "shepherd, and priest of Midian;" however, he is also known to some as one of the prophets in the Qur'an.

He seems also to be revered as a prophet in his own right in the Druze religion. The Druze believe that Jethro was the hidden prophet who inspired Moses, the recognized prophet. Timothy Hogan in 'Entering the Chain of Union' states that according to traditional Druze oral teaching, certain souls in antiquity came to earth (and by some accounts to Egypt in particular) and they all agreed to reincarnate until all humanity had attained Gnosis or Divine Knowledge of God. The names of these souls were then engraved on two tablets, which were then placed inside two hollow pillars – one to withstand fire and one to withstand water. According to their tradition, Jethro was one of these souls, and he initiated Moses into the tradition. Consequently, Jethro is revered by Druze as one of their greatest Prophets.

In Exodus 2:18 Moses's father-in-law is named Reuel, and this is repeated in Numbers 10:29 (where Hobab is described as Reuel's son). In the Hebrew version of Judges 4:11, Hobab is described as Moses's father-in-law, while in others as his brother-in-law.

Comment: Have you considered asking at [judaism.se]? Their sages almost certainly have some thoughts on Jethro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Christianity, but about Druze beliefs.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden, It may be off-topic because it's not about the practice of Christianity (more about Judaic history, perhaps, I agree with Bradimus), but it's a stretch to say the question is simply about the Druze religion.  I believe the OP was merely offering that as insight to his own research (may he be blessed for doing some research before asking his question).

Comment: Modern practitioners of Judaism believe [Jethro was a convert](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/did-jethro-convert-before-or-after-matan-torah) and that he [tried many religions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86050/what-religious-practice-did-yitro-jethro-follow-that-he-would-be-known-as-a-prie) (including [Noahidism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahidism)) before converting to Judaism.  However, it appears no one knows exactly what religions he tried.